# How to map request parameter fields in angular-httpclient?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I have an angular project that has a user registration form that creates the following Registration object which is then passed into a register service. However, the service request parameters are underscore_cased. How can I remap firstName and lastName to first_name and last_name before I send the http request?

```
export class Registration {
  email: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

register(registration: Registration) {
    console.log('Registration submitted', registration);
    return this.http.post(`${environment.authUrl}/auth/register`, registration).pipe(
       catchError(err => {
            console.log('Handling error locally and rethrowing it...', err);
            return throwError(err);
       })
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new object with desired key name and initialize that newly created object with registeration object's value.

```js
register(registration: Registration) {
  const registerUserObject = {
    'first_name' : registration.firstName,
    'last_name' : registration.lastName,
    'email' : registration.email
  } ;
   
  return this.http.post(`${environment.authUrl}/auth/register`, registerUserObject).pipe(...);
}
```